# Java vs. C# class name

Tags: java, c#, class

In **Java**, I can simply have class names like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static String toString(Class<?> classType)
    {
        return classType.getName() ;
    }
}

package this.that;
public class OneClass
{
}

public static void main()
{
   System.out.println(MyClass.toString(OneClass));
}
```

to return me full class name "this.that.OneClass".

I tried same in **C#**, but got error that i'm using OneClass as type.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static String ToString(Type classType)
    {
        return classType.Name ;
    }
}

namespace this.that
{
    public class OneClass
    {
    }
}

static Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(MyClass.ToString(OneClass));  // expecting "this.that.OneClass" result
}
```

*Note that I don't want to use class instance*

Comment: `MyClass.ToString(typeof(OneClass))`

Comment: You can't have `namespace this.that`... at max you can have `namespace @this.that`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, let's fix your Java code: this call

```
System.out.println(MyClass.toString(OneClass));
```

would not compile unless you add `.class` to `OneClass`:

```
System.out.println(MyClass.toString(OneClass.class));
```

The equivalent construct to `.class` syntax in C# is `typeof`. It takes a type name, and produces the corresponding `System.Type` object:

```
Console.WriteLine(MyClass.ToString(typeof(OneClass)));
```

In addition, C# does not allow `this` as an identifier<sup>*</sup>, so you should rename the namespace to exclude the keyword. Finally, `Name` will print the unqualified name of the class. If you would like to see the name with the namespace, use `FullName` property:

```
public static String ToString(Type classType) {
    return classType.FullName;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/0bBdgO)

<sup>*</sup> The language allows you to use `this` if you prefix it with `@`, but one should make every effort to avoid using this trick.

Comment: *"In addition, C# does not allow this as an identifier"* it does if you prefix it with an `@`, but I don't at all recommend it, ever.

Comment: Ah ok, so typeof instead of .class, thx. 

p.s. Wrote java code from head, it was just an example, as well as namespace :) thx for remark anyway

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
Console.WriteLine(MyClass.ToString(OneClass));
```

isn't valid `C#`. You need to do:

```
Console.WriteLine(MyClass.ToString(typeof(OneClass)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use namespaces instead of packages in c#

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static String toString(Type classType)
    {
        // returns the full name of the class including namespace
        return classType.FullName;
    }
}
```

you can use namespace to package classes

```
namespace outerscope.innerscope
{
    public class OneClass
    {
    }
}
```

To print the full name

```
Console.WriteLine(MyClass.toString(typeof(outerscope.innerscope.OneClass)));
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# you of course must use typeof(OneClass) as others suggested.

But your toString method is also wrong, you have to use Type.FullName to get namespace, not just Type.Name